# jQuery and scrolling page to checked radio button on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page with a div #kt which has several radio buttons. jQuery code should check which radio button is checked and sroll page to it. Anyway, the code will not work when page is loaded. Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#kt > input').each(function() {
    var container = $('#kt'),
      scrollTo = $(this);

    if (scrollTo.is(':checked')) {
      var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - ($(window).width() / 2 - scrollTo.width() / 2) + container.scrollLeft();

      container.animate({
        scrollLeft: leftOffset
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="kt" style="display: inline-block; width: 2000px">
<div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-6" class="listaus-valintaruutu" /></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-5" class="listaus-valintaruutu" /></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-4" class="listaus-valintaruutu" /></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-6" class="listaus-valintaruutu" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Why are you trying to scroll left? Are all the radio buttons placed horizontally?

Comment: Yes, there is a very wide div #kt and radio buttons are placed horizontally.

Comment: `#kt > input` means the inputs must be direct child of `#kt`. If it's not, you want to use `#kt input`, which will take all inputs that are children of  `#kt`. Can you post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
$('#kaaviotaulukko input[type=radio]').each(function() {
  var container = $('#kaaviotaulukko'),
    scrollTo = $(this);

  if (scrollTo.is(':checked')) {
    var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - ($(window).width() / 2 - scrollTo.width() / 2) + container.scrollLeft();

    container.animate({
      scrollLeft: leftOffset
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The element which has to be animated to the position you calculated for an `input:checked` is the `body`... Not the container `div`.

I checked one for the test...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#kt input').each(function() {
    var container = $('#kt'),
        scrollTo = $(this);

    if (scrollTo.is(':checked')) {
      var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - ($(window).width() / 2 - scrollTo.width() / 2) + container.scrollLeft();
      console.log(leftOffset);

      //container.animate({
      $("body").animate({
        scrollLeft: leftOffset
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="kt" style="display: inline-block; width: 2000px">
  <div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center">
    <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-6" class="listaus-valintaruutu" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center">
    <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-5" class="listaus-valintaruutu" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center">
    <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-4" class="listaus-valintaruutu" checked/>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 500px; text-align: center">
    <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-6" class="listaus-valintaruutu" />
  </div>
</div>
```